# asynchronous loading BitmapImage from Isolated Storage on Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, asynchronous, isolatedstorage

When downloading images simultaneously using a lot of memory.How to optimize the downloading of images from Isolated Storage

Comment: Show some code of how you are currently doing it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16748383/using-async-await-on-windows-phone-7